# How to Align the text of my webview from html javascript iphone sdk?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, text, alignment

can anyone help me..

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.textAlign = 'right';"];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is pretty vague. Please take a read of http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question to make it easier to answer.

Comment: Can you add some more details about your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align to center in uiwebview, u can use this :

> style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:70%;"